# Help with modelling a sword hilt

Tags: modeling

I'm having some trouble modeling the bottom part og a sword, which you can see in the pictures below. I was wondering if anyone could give me some pointers on how to model something like that, because I'm a little lost ~

[image: Model]
[image: Referance]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many way to model depending on experience, style and end use. Here’s one approach:

1. Delete the default cube.
2. Add a plane > Press SHIFT + “A” and select “Plane” from the drop down menu.
3. Go into Top View > Press “7”.
4. With the plane selected go into “Edit Mode” > Press “TAB”.
5. Subdivide once > Press “W” and select Subdivide from the drop down menu.
6. Select five vertices and delete them > Press “X” and select Vertices from the drop down menu.

[image]

7. Add two Loop Cuts > Press CTRL + “R” > Left click and drag to where you want it then Left click again to set in place.
8. Select three vertices and extrude . Press “E” and drag holding CTRL to snap them to the grid. Left click to set in place.

[image]

9. Add a Mirror Modifier (This can be done any time after step six). Check off boxes “Y” and “Clipping” in the Mirror Modifier panel.

[image]

10. Select all of the vertices. > Go into Front View by pressing “1”. > Press “E” to extrude. > drag downward.

[image]

11. Press “S” to scale outward.

[image]

12. Press “E” to extrude downward.

[image]

[image]

- Add a Subsurf Modifier and set Shading to Smooth to finish it off.